# how to insert every image in a new page to a ( word document )

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileoutputstream

**i'm having some images, and i'm trying to insert each image to a new page in a ( word document ). my code works fine only for one image**

i'm trying to write a program to insert the first image to the first page of the document

and then automatically open a new page to insert the second one and so on

```
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();


        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(  new File("D:\\word java.docx"));

 File image = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\image1.jpg");
 File image2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\image2.jpg");
 File image3 = new File("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\image2.jpg"); // i want to insert those three image in one (Word Document)

 FileInputStream imageData= new FileInputStream(image);


        int imageType = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;
        String imageFileName = image.getName();


        int width = 450;
        int height = 400;


        run.addPicture(imageData, imageType, imageFileName,
                Units.toEMU(width),
                Units.toEMU(height));
        document.write(fout);

        
        fout.close();
        document.close();


    }
}
```

Comment: Why not refactor the working code to introduce a method that can be called repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `setPageBreak()` method. Below is a runnable example how this could be done. Of course, the image paths would  need to reflect the images you want to apply to the WORD document. In the example runnable below, the image paths are placed into a String[] array names `filePaths` and Text to be added to the bottom of these images are placed into a parallel String[] array named `imageTexts`. Each image will be placed into its own document page with its respective text. Please read the comments in code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;


public class Apache_POI_Demo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* These are the images we want to place into a WORD document
           but only one image per page. We place them into a String[]
           Array for easier handling especially if you plan to plan to
           insert lots of them into the document.                 */
        String[] filePaths = {"C:/Users/Devils/Pictures/DUCKS/image1.jpg",  // Image 1
                              "C:/Users/Devils/Pictures/DUCKS/image2.jpg",  // Image 2
                              "C:/Users/Devils/Pictures/DUCKS/image3.jpg"}; // Image 3
        
        /* There are specific Strings related to each image. These 
           strings will be applied under each respective image on 
           each page.                                */
        String[] imageText = {"Just Some Cute Ducks",       // For image1 
                              "A Couple more Cute Ducks!",  // For image2 
                              "A Bit Of A Happy Duck"};     // For image3
        
        // Create a new WORD document ('Try With Resources' used!)
        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument()) {
                // The pages we want (one page for each image).
                XWPFParagraph[] page = new XWPFParagraph[filePaths.length];
                
                /* Iterate through each image, load it in, 
                   and apply it to the document.        */
                for (int pg = 0; pg < filePaths.length; pg++) {
                    // New paragraph for this current page.
                    page[pg] = doc.createParagraph();
                    // Align everything to center
                    page[pg].setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
                    
                    // Create Page
                    XWPFRun run = page[pg].createRun();
                    
                    // Load Image File... 
                    File image = new File(filePaths[pg]);
                    // 'Try With Resources' used! here as well.
                    try (FileInputStream imageData = new FileInputStream(image)) {
                        int imageType = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;  // Image type is jpg
                        String imageFileName = image.getName();          // Get image file Name (only)
                        int width = 450;                                 // Set image Width
                        int height = 400;                                // Set image Height
                        
                        // Add image as first paragraph in document page.
                        run.addPicture(imageData, imageType, imageFileName,
                                Units.toEMU(width),
                                Units.toEMU(height));
                        
                        // Add text center under image ("Image #n") as part of first paragraph.
                        run.setFontFamily("Courier");               // Set the Font name for text.
                        run.setBold(true);                          // Set Text Bold.
                        run.setItalic(true);                        // Set Text Italic.
                        run.setColor("0000ff");                     // Set text color Blue (hex RGB color value).
                        run.setFontSize(11);                        // Set the Font Size for this text.
                        run.setText("Image #" + (pg + 1));          // The text to add to document...
                        run.setText(" - " + imageFileName);         // The text to add to document line.
                        
                        // Add a second paragraph to document on current page.
                        XWPFParagraph paragraph2 = doc.createParagraph();
                        // Also align this paragraph text to center of document.
                        paragraph2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
                        // Create the paragraph 2 object
                        XWPFRun run2 = paragraph2.createRun();
                        run2.setFontFamily("Time New Roman");       // Set the Font for this paragraph
                        run2.setBold(false);                        // Set Font Bold OFF
                        run2.setItalic(false);                      // Set Font italic OFF
                        run2.setFontSize(14);                       // Set the Font Size to 14
                        run2.setText(imageText[pg]);                // Apply the desired text from Array
                        page[pg].setPageBreak(true);                // Apply a new Page Break.  ******
                    }
                }

            // Save (Write) the WORD Document.
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\POI_test\\word java.docx")) {
                doc.write(out);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

With the Images **I used**, the following was the result within WORD:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have already got how to add pictures into a `XWPFRun`. So your question now seems to be how to do that multiple times for different picture file paths and how to put page breaks after each inserted picture.

For the first we would need a loop. Put the pictures paths into a `List`. Then you can loop over all picture paths using a "for-each" loop.

For the second we take a look into the API documentation of [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html). There we find [XWPFRun.addBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addBreak-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType-) -> [BreakType.PAGE](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/BreakType.html#PAGE).

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CreateWordPicturesInSinglePages {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> picturePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
  picturePaths.add("./image1.jpg");
  picturePaths.add("./image2.jpg");
  picturePaths.add("./image3.jpg");

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The pictures: ");

  FileInputStream in;
  File image;
  // a loop over all picture paths
  for (String picturePath : picturePaths) {
   try { // maybe something gets wrong while image IO
    image = new File(picturePath);
    in = new FileInputStream(image);
    int imageType = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;
    String imageFileName = image.getName();
    int width = 450;
    int height = 400;
    
    // add picture 
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addPicture(in, imageType, imageFileName, Units.toEMU(width), Units.toEMU(height));
    
    // add text below the picture
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Image file-name: " + imageFileName);
   
    // add page break
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordPicturesInSinglePages.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

The code is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.2.2`.

Result in Word:

[image]